# Prolog Recursion and Termination

Tags: recursion, prolog

first StackOverflow question.

I'm writing a predicate in prolog that takes three parameters. These are (respectively) a character, a list of strings, and the last parameter is a list of all the strings in the second parameter that start with the first parameter. My write statements are a substitution for my complete lack of knowledge on how to trace in SWI-Prolog. Anyway, on to the code!

---

```
startString(C, [H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    atom_chars(H1, [C| _ ]),
    H2 = H1,
    startString(C, T1, T2).

startString(C, [ _ |T1], Y) :-
    startString(C, T1, Y),
    write(foo).

startString(_, [], []) :-
    write(foo).
```

---

Which outputs:

---

```
foofoofoo

X = [some, simple]
```

---

My methodology is correct, but the predicate doesn't *terminate* (the lack of period after the write of X isn't a mistake). My question is, why isn't it? From the limited examples of recursion I've found on the internet, the third version of my predicate should terminate the predicate and make x a definite answer.

When I press enter I'm able to enter another query, but I have this same little "issue" in another predicate I wrote in the same program. Any help with this predicate should also carry over to the other. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on your question in your comments to @ScottHunter,

> I guess my question is, why do my other predicates "Know" they have the right answer, while this and one more do not?

The answer has to do with the existence of choice points on the stack. Consider this situation:

```
reasonably_big(L, X) :- member(X, L), X > 100.

?- reasonably_big([105, 2], X).
X = 105 ;
false.
?-
```

Compare that to this:

```
?- reasonably_big([2, 105], X).
X = 105.
?-
```

In the second case, Prolog "knew" that there were no more solutions; in the first case it did not. The difference between these two situations is that in the first case `member` had left a *choice point* on the stack: there was still another item in the list it could consider to find another answer. In the second case, the remainder of the list was empty, and SWI-Prolog's `member` is smart enough to not leave a choice point on the stack in that case, so it never asked you if you wanted another solution.

If you're getting extraneous choice points, it often points to a logic error. For example, consider this definition of `min`:

```
min(X, Y, X) :- X =< Y.
min(X, Y, Y).
```

This is defective, because you can always backtrack in and get the other value; to wit:

```
?- min(3,4, X).
X = 3 ;
X = 4.
```

The second solution there is erroneous. But you can still wind up with an unnecessary choice point by making the wrong improvement:

```
min(X, Y, X) :- X =< Y.
min(X, Y, Y) :- Y =< X.
```

See what happens when we try different values:

```
?- min(4,3,X).
X = 3.
?-

?- min(3,4,X).
X = 3 ;
false.
?-
```

The first one worked fine but the second one left a choice point on the stack by having a second body. You can eliminate it with a green cut:

```
min(X,Y,X) :- X =< Y, !.
min(X,Y,Y) :- Y =< X.

?- min(3,4,X).
X = 3.
?-

?- min(4,3,X).
X = 3.
?-
```

The cut commits Prolog to a particular solution. It says, once you've made it here, there's no need to try any other solutions for this predicate, because we've found the only one we want. Understanding how to apply the cut is a complex topic, but eliminating undesirable choice points is an important use.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem, and it has to do with cut. It's a complicated topic I'm still not entirely sure I understand, but adding it to the end of the versions of my predicates allowed prolog to "Stop" the way I wanted to. I think it has a lot to do with the recursion and the method I chose to solve this problem. Thank you for your in-depth answer, it's going to help me with the other prolog assignments I have!

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about what you mean by "terminate" in Prolog.  The fact that you got a value bound to X when you asked prolog to prove startString('s',some-list,X) means that it terminated (else it would still be searching for a value for X).  But in another sense it has not, because you can ask (typically by entering a semi-colon) Prolog to try and find another solution, and can keep asking until it exhausts the possibilities of doing so.  It sounds like your console is waiting for you to tell it whether you want to try and find another solution, or that you are done (which is what happens when you hit enter, and the interpreter allows you to enter a new query).

Comment: It sounds like your console is waiting for you to tell it whether you want to try and find another solution

I guess my question is, why do my other predicates "Know" they have the right answer, while this and one more do not? How can I let the interpreter know that it succeeds?

Comment: Could you give me an example of a predicate that "knows" it has the right answer?  And its not so much that its not the right answer; as far as the interpreter is concerned they are ALL right answers.  The fact that you didn't ask the interpreter to find another answer lets it know that you don't want another answer.

Comment: Here's an example of a "correct" predicate:

'altElement([],[]).

altElement([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :- H2 is H1, removeElem(T1,[H2|T2]).

removeElem([],[_]).

removeElem([_|T1],[_|T2]) :- altElement(T1,T2).
'

The predicate takes a list, and returns the first, third, fifth.... etc. element in a new list if the second parameter is a variable.

Comment: And if you ask to prove altElement([1,2,3],X), it comes back with X = [1,5] but DOESN'T allow you to ask for an alternate solution?

Comment: It comes back with X = [1,3]. 

Then the terminal is ready for another predicate inquiry, displaying ?-

Comment: And if you enter ; after you get your first answer for startString, you get a different value for X, one with the last item missing?  Sounds like Prolog is being a bit more clever than I gave it credit, in that it determines that there is no alternate answer before you explicitly ask (and hence doesn't give you the opportunity to.  Note that, in startString, if you ask for another answer, it can "reject" a successful application of the first rule, but still succeed with the second, at the cost of losing an item in the list.

Comment: I think that because of how I phrased my question you might have had a slight misunderstanding as to what problem I was attempting to solve with the predicate. But thank you so much for your help anyway, it did provide some valuable context for me "fixing" what I needed to.